# Ambiguity in raising/lowering the index of a tensor

Tags: tensors

I'm reading Sean Carroll's GR book, where it's written:

> The metric and inverse metric can be used to **raise or lower** indices on tensors. That is, given a tensor $T^{\alpha\beta}_{\ \ \ \ \ \gamma\delta}$, we can use the metric to define new tensors, which we choose to denote by the same letter $T$:
> $$T^{\alpha\beta\mu}_{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \delta}=\eta^{\mu\gamma}T^{\alpha\beta}_{\ \ \ \ \ \gamma\delta}\tag{1}$$
> $$T_{\mu}^{\ \ \beta}\ _{\gamma\delta}=\eta_{\mu\alpha}T^{\alpha\beta}_{\ \ \ \ \ \gamma\delta}\tag{2}$$
> $$T_{\mu\nu}^{\ \ \ \ \rho\sigma}=\eta_{\mu\alpha}\eta_{\nu\beta}\eta^{\rho\gamma}\eta^{\sigma\delta}T^{\alpha\beta}_{\ \ \ \ \ \gamma\delta}\tag{3}$$

I tried connecting this to what I've studied in math so far. There's this theorem (Theorem 6.3.4 in Newman's Semi-Riemannian Geometry)

> Let $(V,g)$ be a scalar product space, let $H$ be a basis for $V$, and let $g_H^{-1}=[g^{ij}]$ (i.e. $g^{ij}$ are the elements of the inverse of the metric's matrix representation w.r.t. basis $H$). Let $T\in\mathcal{T}^r_s(V)$, and let $1\leq k\leq r+1$ and $1\leq l\leq s$ be integers. Then the tensor $S^k_l(T)$ in $\mathcal{T}^{r+1}_{s-1}(V)$ has the components
> $$S^k_l(T)^{i_1\ldots i_{r+1}}_{j_1\ldots j_{s-1}}=g^{i_k p}T^{i_1\ldots \hat i_k\ldots i_{r+1}}_{j_1\ldots j_{l-1}pj_l\ldots j_{s-1}}\tag{4}$$
> with respect to $H$.

where $S^k_l$ is the $(k,l)$ sharp map. Basically this raises the lower index in the $l$-th position and puts it in the $k$-th upper position.

If I only look at the RHS, $l$ is unambiguous - it's just the position of the index that's repeated. As was done in Carroll's book, let's say I'm trying to raise an index of $T^{\alpha\beta}_{\ \ \ \ \ \gamma\delta}$ with the metric: $\eta^{\mu\gamma}T^{\alpha\beta}_{\ \ \ \ \ \gamma\delta}$. **Why does the LHS of eq. $(1)$ equal $T^{\alpha\beta\mu}_{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \delta}$ (this corresponds to a $(3,1)$ sharp map)? It could just as well have been $T^{\alpha\mu\beta}_{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \delta}$ or $T^{\mu\alpha\beta}_{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \delta}$ depending on if we were applying a $(2,1)$ or a $(1,1)$ sharp map**.

And regarding the LHS of eq. $(2)$, what even is that? Of course the ambiguity on where $\mu$ will go remains, depending on the kind of flat map being applied. But what's up with $T_{\mu}^{\ \ \beta}\ _{\gamma\delta}$ - shouldn't it have been $T^{\beta}_{\ \ \ \mu\gamma\delta}$?

Comment: Of the two books I only have Carroll's so I just comment on that. You are raising/lowering indices of tensor *components*. The tensor is the multilinear map
$$
\mathbf{T}={{T_\mu}^\beta}_{\gamma\delta}\,dx^\mu\otimes\partial_\beta\otimes dx^\gamma\otimes dx^\delta
$$
which eats vectors in the first, third and fourth slot and a covector in the second slot. This should tell you what the left hand side of (2) is and how this differs from (1). Since the other book ignores the horizontal index position could it be that that author considers only less general multilinear maps?

Comment: @KurtG.: I thought so too (i.e. the tensor equation you wrote), but I got doubts because it seems like a map $V\times V^*\times V\times V\to\mathbb{R}$. Whereas wherever I've read the multilinear map definition of tensors (Carroll included), it's a map from $V^*\times\ldots\times V^*\times V\times\ldots\times V\to\mathbb{R}$. Basically the first $k$ arguments are covectors and the remaining $l$ are vectors.

Comment: aha so there’s your issue. You’re too narrow with the definition (as are many textbooks, because it gets obvious after a certain stage). There’s no reason to insist on keeping that ordering of the $V^*$ and $V$. See [Order of arguments in a 1-1 tensor](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4625371/568204) for some remarks on this.

Comment: ^ I restricted to the $(1,1)$ case in that discussion, but clearly the remarks about ordering and metric duality apply to any $(r,s)$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Thanks! So one follow-up (using the coordinate notation to denote the whole tensor for brevity): suppose for $T_{\mu}^{\ \ \beta}\ _{\gamma\delta}:V\times V^*\times V\times V\to\mathbb{R}$, suppose I take $T^{\beta}_{\ \ \ \mu\gamma\delta}:V^*\times V\times V\times V\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for any $\omega\in V^*$ and $u,v,w\in V$, the former's action on $(u,\omega,v,w)$ equals the latter's action on $(\omega,u,v,w)$. Then that will establish an isomorphism between $V\times V^*\times V\times V\to\mathbb{R}$ maps and $V^*\times V\times V\times V\to\mathbb{R}$ maps ... (cont'd)

Comment: ...(cont'd) meaning that we can identify $T_{\mu}^{\ \ \beta}\ _{\gamma\delta}$ with $T^{\beta}_{\ \ \ \mu\gamma\delta}$. So is there any practical use of this generalization in which the ordering of $V^*$ and $V$ is changed?

Comment: The benefit is that you can now raise/lower indices using the metric, “in place” (as they say in CS), and you don’t run into your aforementioned confusion. So, given an $(r,s)$ tensor on $V$, $T:W=W_1\times\cdots\times W_{r+s}\to\Bbb{R}$ (where $r$ of the $W_i$’s are $V^*$ and the remaining $s$ of them are $V$) we can now use the metric to raise/lower indices to get a new tensor $T_{g,i}:\tilde{W}\to\Bbb{R}$, where now $\tilde{W}$ is obtained from $W$ by replacing the $W_i$ (which is $V$ or $V^*$) with the opposite one, using the metric isomorphism.

Comment: For example, given a $(1,3)$ tensor as you’ve written, $V\times V^*\times V\times V\to\Bbb{R}$, I can now use the metric isomorphism on the third factor (raising an index) to now give me a $(2,2)$ tensor $V\times V^*\times V^*\times V\to\Bbb{R}$. I don’t need to fuss over permuting this to get $V^*\times V^*\times V\times V\to\Bbb{R}$ so that it lines up perfectly with the typical textbook definition.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Thanks! I'll take a bit of time to think about your last 2 comments. But I'm not really clear on how ambiguity is resolved for eq. $(1)$ - i.e. my question in bold in the post, without spelling out whether it's a $(1,1)$ or $(2,1)$ or $(3,1)$ sharp map..

Comment: The summation index tells you what to do. You have four indices on your original $T^{\alpha\beta}_{\,\,\,\,\,\,\gamma\delta}$ and they appear in that specific ordering meaning you have a multilinear map $V^*\times V^*\times V\times V\to\Bbb{R}$. Now, equation (1) has a summation over $\gamma$ which is the third index, i.e it is the third factor in $V^*\times V^*\times V\times V$. You now convert that $V$ into a $V^*$ so you now get $V^*\times V^*\times V^*\times V\to\Bbb{R}$. Hence, $T^{\alpha\beta\mu}_{\,\,\,\,\quad\delta}$.

Comment: This ‘in place’ raising/lowering is the universal convention in SR/GR. If you now want to permute the factors, you can do so, just say that you’re doing so.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Aha! Now I get it. So it's another convention that I should be aware of. If you can formulate all that in the form of an answer, I'll mark that as accepted

Comment: you should write your own answer, you’ll remember it better that way (and I’m too lazy to write an answer now:)

Comment: Whenever I run into a situation like this, I set up my own notation and do the same calculations but using my notation. That's often less trouble than trying to understand someone else's notation. Also, with calculations like this, errors are common. It's hard to be sure whether a calculation in a book or paper is wrong or not, but it is often easier to check your own calculation.